# Why do I have to hit 'Q' at the end of 'git log'?

Tags: git

Consider:

```
git log -n 20 --pretty=oneline
```

I am telling Git that I need to see only the last 20 commits. I hate to hit <kbd>Q</kbd> to get rid of END. Is there a way out so that I don't have to hit <kbd>Q</kbd>?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Git is automatically paging the output for you, since logs tend to easily overflow a single terminal window size (you're in one of the rare exceptions - a oneline format and a small commit limit). If you don't want this, use:

```
git --no-pager log -n 20 --pretty=oneline
```

Note that this does mean you'll get some ugly wrapping, because the pager was previously turning off wrapping for you (since you could use the cursor keys to scroll left-right).

Comment: @DeckTrout Without any information, no one can help you. If you can manage to be specific about your setup, you might try asking a new question. This answer worked for the OP here (and a lot of others) so clearly something's different for you.

Comment: Add `l = !git --no-pager log -n 20 --pretty=oneline` in `.gitconfig` to create an alias..

Comment: On Git For Windows, this alters the highlight of "commit insert-hash-here" from Orange to Yellow.

Answer (score 30):

You can "turn off" git paging by telling it to use cat instead of less.  Thereafter, pipe the output through less when you do want paging, or head if you just want to see the top, etc.

```
git config --global core.pager cat
```

I turn off automatic paging because I often run git from within emacs, which neither needs nor plays well with less.

Comment: My git log doesn't end with a newline, so the shell prompt following the log is on the same line as my oldest commit. Nice tip nonetheless, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

`less` accepts `-F` argument to quit automatically if content fits on one screen

Answer (score 9):

`git log -n 20 --pretty=oneline | cat`

is a little shorter that the `--no-pager` option but will also remove any colours present.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `--no-pager` in an alias, set up your alias this way:

```
hist = !git --no-pager log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short
```

Answer (score 1):

If short is what you want, `-P` is a synonym for `--no-pager` which turns off pagination.

Some fun examples:

```
    git --no-pager log --pretty=oneline -10  # summarize last 10 commits
    git -P log --pretty=oneline -10          # same!

    git -P log -1 -c    # show diffs for last commmit
    git -P log -1 -U1   # unified diffs w/ 1 line of context

    git -P log -1 --name-only  # print commit + names of changed files
```

Answer (score 0):

The q is used to close [the command line program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) used to view the logs...

You can use another log viewer, like gitk:

```
gitk -n 20
```

Comment: gitk is useful to view graphs etc. I was looking for a lightweight solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alias for a log command where you don't have to click `q` to to make it go away:

```
git config --global alias.hist '!git --no-pager log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short --max-count=10'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to automatically turn off pagination when the contents of the log fits on the terminal screen:

`git config --global core.pager "less -F"`

For older versions of `less` (< 530), you might have to do:

`git config --global core.pager "less -FX"`