# How to make git log not prompt to continue?

Tags: git

I have a couple of git repositories that belong together, and simple batch/bash file to loop over them. I often loop over them with a log command to quickly see what state they are in. This works nicely, except for one thing: if the commit message is longer than the number of characters my console is wide (or has multiple lines), git shows the line, then a newline with (END) and I have to press *q* to continue (I guess it pipes the output through *more* or something like that).
Example:

```
> gitloop . "git log --decorate=short --pretty=oneline -n1"
18629ae238e9d5832cb3535ec88274173337a501 (HEAD, origin/master, master) short log

625fb891b9b0b8648459b07ace662ae3b7773c7f (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) short log

dc0838118266ba8570ea338c1faddfe8af0387bb (HEAD, origin/work, origin/master, work, master) oops loooooooooooooong log
-(END)
```

This is rather inconvenient as I have to press *q* a couple of time, whereas I'd just like to see all those oneliners in one go.

How can I disable this behaviour (preferrably while still keeping this log format)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why do I have to hit q at the end of git log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364978/why-do-i-have-to-hit-q-at-the-end-of-git-log)

Comment: Thanks, the SEO worked and I found this!

My main use case is different: I want to scroll back in terminal and be able to see the commit hashes from where I was the *last* time I ran `git log`. For some reason the Page prevents this in iTerm.

The answers here all worked. Great.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Git has an option to disable the pager:

```
git --no-pager log --decorate=short --pretty=oneline -n1
```

If your pager cuts lines and you want to retain that behaviour, either pipe to `cut`...

```
git --no-pager log --decorate=short --pretty=oneline -n1 | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS
```

...or set the environment variable `GIT_PAGER` before the invocation:

```
GIT_PAGER="cut -c 1-${COLUMNS-80}" git log --decorate=short --pretty=oneline -n1
```

Comment: Is there a way to make `--no-pager` the default or even better at a shortcut for this option when needed ?
I thought of aliasing `gitnp` to `git --no-pager`, but I think there is a better solution.

Comment: @IslamAzab, you could alias `git` to `/usr/bin/git --no-pager` which would disable the pager for all your git calls.

Comment: @WarrenP `git` does not have built in pager. Instead, it follows Unix philosophy and uses whatever you have in `$PAGER`. `git` simply always uses `$PAGER` instead of doing that only randomly unlike many other poorly written tools. The only magic `git` has is that if `$LESS` is *not defined*, it will define `$LESS` to value `FRX`. See around https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/config.txt#L766 for more details.

Comment: @WarrenP `git` simply provides an *override* `GIT_PAGER` that will allow you to define custom value to be used instead of `PAGER` whenever git needs paging.

Comment: Simplest case that fixes the behavior just for git: export GIT_PAGER=cat

Comment: @IslamAzab  `-P` is an alias for `--no-pager`, for example, `git -P log -1 --name-only`.

Answer (score 52):

Another solution for the problem of permanently disabling **pager** specifically when using `log` subcommand:

- for current repo only:
    `git config pager.log false`
- for your git installation (i. e. all repos on your machine):
  `git config --global pager.log false`

As you can guess, the same works if **pager** is needed to be *on* or *off* for some other subcommands selectively.
E. g. for `branch` (which prints branches) subcommand it will be

`git config pager.branch false`

---

Proposed solution is arguably more elegant comparing to

- using `git --no-pager` each time you run certain command.
  Because, quite possible, you don't want to type it each time.
- specifying `git --no-pager` as an alias for `git`
  Because, quite possible, you want to avoid *implicit* global config OR you want **pager** to be enabled in some cases.
- rely on some environment variables like `PAGER` or `GIT_PAGER`.
  Because to do that, you need to ensure they're set in your current terminal session. And, if you want them to be set to some custom value automatically each time your new terminal is created, you need to alter one of shell-bootstrapped files like e. g. `~/.bashrc`. It's not a big problem. But these bootstrapped files frequently are altered by other applications as well and contain bunch of other stuff, not just that used by Git. So, in theory, it's better to specify git-related settings using `git config` rather than put them in e. g. `~/.bashrc`.

---

The alternative solution for disabling `pager` for **all subcommands** is to specify `cat` as the utility git will use for paging:

- `git config core.pager cat` OR
- `git config --global core.pager cat`

---

My answer is somewhat rephrasing of the one below:
"prevent git diff from using a pager?"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6986231/6103242

It's referenced to point out another relevant discussion.

Comment: Once I do this is it possible to do something like `git --pager log` when I actually want it from time to time?

Comment: @Arsen I don't think it's directly supported. `git help log` page does not have any mention about `pager` as an option. What you can do though is to add custom wrapper-function in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` file so it does 3 things: switches the pager ON, executes `git log`, switches the pager OFF.

`gitLogWithPager() { git config pager.log true; git log ${@}; git config pager.log false; }`

Reopen your terminal and then you should be able to use `gitLogWithPager` command. `${@}` forwards any additional arguments to `git log`.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer, think it should be the accepted one

Answer (score 9):

Disable pager for all commands:

```
git config --global core.pager ''
```

Comment: This works great! On Windows + Powershell use (double quotes inside single quotes): git config --global core.pager '""'

Answer (score 3):

You pipe it to `less -F` in case `--no-pager` does not work for you.

```
git log --decorate --oneline -5 | less -F
```

`-F` means that `less` will behave like `--no-pager` if the output fits on one screen, but become a pager otherwise.

Comment: That still paginates, though.  Piping it to `cat` would avoid that.

Comment: Piping to `cat` is ideal if you have a bash alias like `alias glo="git log --color=always --pretty=tformat:'%C(brightblue)%h %C(white)%as %C(cyan)%an %C(green)%d %C(reset)%s'"`

Answer (score 3):

```
export PAGER=cat
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answers are probably correct, I would like add one that suites me best. I recommend configure `less` instead of `git` by adding the following flags:

```
export LESS="${LESS:+$LESS }-X -F"
```

```
-X  Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.
-F or --quit-if-one-screen -> no need to press `q` if output fits into the current terminal size.
```