# git log requires me to press enter to see all log files

Tags: git, github, gitlab

So, I have googled and looked through stackoverflow and various other forums – but I'm still perplexed. I have access to a git repository that contains files (templates) I have to use. The files could change at any given moment. So before I start a new job, I `git pull` to get the latest files into my local repository.

And sometimes, I am curious and want to know what has changed. So I do a `git pull` to see what has changed in which files.

**Problem:** Perhaps there is a limit to how many results get returned by default, but I usually get a whole bunch of results on my command line tool, and then I see a colon, just like this `:`

[image]

After that, I have to press the enter key until one result of the remaining files shows up, then it's back to the colon `:` (Note: I just pressed the enter key 50+ times to see the rest of the results.)

What am I missing? Any links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you guys voting me down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git --no-pager log`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7737071/226781

Also, if you hit the space bar instead of pressing Enter, you'll go a page at a time instead of a line at a time.

Comment: Thank you! It's been a while since I worked with git, or the command line, so I appreciate your help. Keep on being awesome!